# selected text incorrect if options have more than one space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I have created a bootstrap multiselect:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="providers" style="width:100%;">Provider :</label>
                                        <select id="providers" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
                                            @foreach (var providers in @ViewBag.Providers)
                                            {
                                                <option value=@providers>@providers</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.providerString)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

The options in @ViewBag.Providers are: Dr A B, Dr B C, Dr P Q, Dr periciado

After selecting multiple values, it always shows "Dr A B" in the selected textbox. I removed the spaces from the options value and it works correctly but it is not working with the values having multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try putting quotes around the option's value?

`<option value="@providers">@providers</option>`

instead of

`<option value=@providers>@providers</option>`